# Nest client getting user quota

Tags: nest-api

Is there any option getting user quota programmatically for client?
I just searched the API REFERENCE page and the doc but there is no reference to that?

How can my company track the user quota per client?

Comment: What do you mean by user quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically get the user quota.  You can track the user quota for a client on the [Clients](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/user-limits#user-quota) configuration page of the developer portal.